# Recurring Crashes in App's Early Life Cycle Not Reported on iOS

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

We have been having issues with our Core Data stack in our production iOS app lately and Fabric Crashlytics helped us a lot to solve most of them. However, we suspect that not all crashes are reported even after the app has been relaunched by a user to send the crash report.

In a scenario where an app gets into a **recurring crash loop on app launch**, Crashlytics may not report any of the crashes that occurred. From Fabric's documentation:

> If your app crashes on launch, on the subsequent launch we will try
>   to send a crash report synchronously blocking the main thread for a
>   short period of time.

- https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#control-submission-behavior

The above main thread blocking never happens, and because of that app crashes again before Crashlytics has a chance to send a report; the original crash is never reported.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])

        Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash() // Mimics our CoreData stack crash.

        return true
    }
}
```

Are we doing something wrong? Is there a way to configure Crashlytics to enable this feature?

*Note that we tried using other methods to crash the app (e.g. force unwrap), the debugger is not attached when testing, Fabric & Crashlytics pods are setup correctly and reporting works for a crash that is not recurring.*

Comment: If your app crashes prior to `Fabric.with` being called, there's no way for it (or any other 3rd party tool) to report anything.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Fabric is the only crash reporting tool that we use and it setup first. So that is not the problem.

Comment: Wait, so you're saying the code you posted doesn't result in a crash report?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Given when the crash is happening, the line after the init, it's almost certain that our SDK hasn't had enough time to finish initializing. Most app crashes on launch happen later in the launch sequence giving our SDK enough time to initialize.

Comment: @MikeBonnell You are right! I have tested this by allowing the first launch to be successful (Not crashing). Crashes on all subsequent launches where properly reported!

Comment: Thanks, switched to providing an answer.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I'm experiencing something similar but my app crashes way after the app is launched and on some user action. However the app crash is reported only when I relaunch the app. Would it be possible to get the crash log to Firebase instantly?

Comment: I haven't worked on the product for a few years, but to my understanding, no. The crash is sent on relaunch of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. Given when the crash is happening, the line after the init, it's almost certain that our SDK hasn't had enough time to finish initializing. Most app crashes on launch happen later in the launch sequence giving our SDK enough time to initialize.

Don't deliberately cause a crash until the app is active in Fabric otherwise you may prevent the app from activating in Fabric.